# Creating a Price Alert on Trading View Using Pine: Dividing one stock price by another Stock price

Tags: pine-script, alert, tradingview-api, price

I am new to Pine and I am currently trying to create a price alert that will notify me when the price of one stock divided by the price of another stock is above a certain amount. Please advise me on how to do this I am truly lost

not sure how to start

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function to get the price from other asset.

Something like below:

```
ibm_close = request.security("NYSE:IBM", timeframe.period, close)
```

Then do your calculation and use the [alert](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Alerts.html?highlight=alert#alert-function-events) function to trigger your alert.